# Datatables Editor Delete

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using Datatables with datatables editor.  i implemented a table like is shown in the following example.  Tables displays correctly and i can check/uncheck the boxes.  When i click the delete button i get the following error

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/tabControl.html

TypeError: this[a7F] is not a function
...n";var a7F="fnGetSelectedIndexes";var c=thisa7F;if(c.length!==0){var d=b[f2]...

Answer (score 0):

made sure I had most recent version of both plugins.  resolved the issue